# Use the same cell type in different screens in storyboard without duplication

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I have a `UITableViewController` using many different types of cells.

In the code, each of those cells has its own `UITableViewCell` subclass.

In storyboard, they are all in the same screen.

Now I need to use the same cells in other screens as well.

How do I do that without having to copy and paste my cell in storyboard in the new screens?

I don't want any duplication in storyboard when it comes to layout and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to move the cells into separate XIB files. You need to use the `registerNib:` method on UITableView to tell the table where it can find the cell definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 
    UITableViewCell 
class.

Use this class as the cell's custom class and Ctrl link your cell's items to the property in this class.

Then you can use this cell class for other table views